# reassign values in one table, based on value in another table in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a table in matlab ("data_table"), and I would like to reassign some values to NaN by looking up a logical "1" in another table - ("artifact_table").  All cells which have a 1 need to be assigned a NaN value in "data_table"

[image]

[image]
so the end result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if it's possible to directly do this in one line of code, but you can do the following using a temporary variable (from the docs [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html#mw_6ee6110b-fb1d-498f-9580-b7d69514d561)). This assumes you haven't changed the name of the second dimension in the table from its default value `Variables`.

```matlab
data = data_table.Variables;
data(artifact_table.Variables == 1) = NaN;
data_table.Variables = data;
```

Comment: You could avoid the temporary variable by some ugly trick like `data_table.Variables = data_table.Variables.*~artifact_table.Variables./~artifact_table.Variables`